# Running a "show databases;" query resulted in "No database selected" error, but only for the first time

Tags: mysql, sql, command-line, command-line-interface

What I did is navigated to the folder where the MySQL is installed:

```
cd /usr/local/mysql/bin/
```

then logged in:

```
$ ./mysql -u root -p
```

and tried to see databases available:

```
mysql-> show databases;
```

So I got this error:

> ERROR 1046 (3D000): No database selected

Now that was confusing... And that happened only once. I tried to execute the same query like 30 seconds later (while I was still logged in), and I got the normal result - the list of available databases.

What caused the query failure at first attempt ? I have tried to repeat the steps, and I can't reproduce the issue anymore.

I am on OSX Sierra.

Answer (score 1):

I am not 100percent sure but this is a bug in older mysql servers that require to SELECT a database prior to use any other queries althogh they are"meta" queries.

Comment: Seems like a bug yeah.

Comment: Confirmed... Well known bug. Update your mysql or update it to a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

That's a wired thing to happen. What happen when you use [`mysqlshow`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlshow.html) command like below. does it lists out all the databases?

```
mysqlshow -u root -p
```

Comment: It lists all the databases, yeah. As I mentioned, running a `show databases;` query (after successful login) didn't work only once, for the first time. Every further attempt (eg. I logout, then login) works as it should...